# GKE custom resources with cloud composer cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

We have a cloud composer setup within a GCP project. For some requirement, an intern created a GKE cluster having 3 nodes. The nodes have enough CPU and memory left out as of now.

We have an another requirement to setup postgress SQL within GKE. Since we have enough space in the GKE node pool created for the cloud composer can we reuse the same? Or a new GKE cluster has to be create?

Went through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257347/creating-composer-environment-in-existing-gke-cluster). It explains creating a composer on existing GKE. But our scenario is vice-versa.

Comment: Is your problem still unresolved?

Comment: Its resolved @MikołajGłodziak., Thanks, We created a Postgress SQL within a new GKE cluster.

Comment: Please, post your solution as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer for better visibility.

Problem is resolved, as [Nishchal Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16312636/nishchal-dinesh) has mentioned in the comment:

> We created a Postgress SQL within a new GKE cluster.